# org.mongodb.scala: Get value from returned document

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have the following script in scala to retrieve a document matching certain criteria. I also use the Helpers.scala file to print the results in the console.

```
val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017")
val db: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("quotedb")
val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = db.getCollection("quotes")
val value = collection.find().projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("_id"))).first().printResults()
```

printResults() returns the results in a document-like format like the following:

*{ "_id" : "MSFT" }*

Is there a way to only print "MSFT" without the quotes, the "_id" or the brackets? A possible solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022302/mongodb-scala-query-document-for-a-specific-field-value) requires that I use the com.mongodb driver instead of org.mongodb.scala I currently use (and which I'd like to keep).

Thank you very much

Comment: What's the type of `printResults`? I'd be surprised if it wasn't `Unit`. Edit: [so it is](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/examples/src/test/scala/tour/Helpers.scala#L42).

Answer (score 3):

The `printResults` helper is just for demonstration purposes and isn't expected to be used in applications as it doesn't return anything.  It can be useful for debugging purposes.

The `first()` method returns a `SingleObservable[Document]` and to get the `_id` from a document you can just call the getter from a map eg: `document("_id")`. Documents in the Scala driver are typesafe and all the values will be `BsonValue`. If `_id` is always a `String` you can unbox the `String` from the `BsonValue` like so: `document.getString("_id")`.

The `printResults` helper just calls `println(_)` on each result in the `Observable` so to just print the `_id` values you will need to transform the `Observable[Document]` to an `Observable[String]` via the `map` function:

```
  collection
    .find()
    .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("_id")))
    .first()
    .map(d => d.getString("_id"))
    .printResults()
```